# Copy a string to a *struct member

Tags: c, struct, strcpy

I've looked through topics of similar kind, but didn't find a solution for my problem. I've got a struct like

```
typedef struct {
    int number;
    char *string;
} mystruct;
    
//Then define a pointer to the struct:
mystruct *data;
    
// Allocate memory:
data = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    
//Assign some number, let's say 5:
(*data).number = 5;
    
//So far ok, works (checked: 5 can be retrieved from the struct somewhere else) but:
    
strcpy((*data).string = "Hello!");
//This line fails with segmentation fault.
```

I don't understand why? Can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because member `char *string;` also needs a memory allocation to copy a string. But you can do `data->string = "Hello!"` to assign the pointer.

Comment: `strcpy()` needs two arguments.

Comment: When you write your question, please use the correct tools in the editor to format text as code.  It's far more effort to insert HTML line breaks than it is to highlight the code and press the `{}` button.  And the latter will actually produce something that doesn't burn our eyes.

Comment: BTW, we normally write `pointer->member` rather than `(*pointer).member`

Comment: I suspect you actually write `strcpy((*data).string, "Hello!");`, otherwise it wouldn't even compile. In that case, see @WeatherVane's comment.

Comment: `strcpy((*data).string = "Hello!");` should fail to compile -- if you are not seeing an error message, adjust your compiler settings

Comment: Yes, sorry very much for all the typos. I've been really, really tired yesterday, just typed and went to sleep. :) Actually, strcpy argument is, of course, with semicolon, not assignment, and even the string in struct is fixed length ([256]), so memory allocation inside the struct should be obsolete... . Doesn't work anyway

Comment: Found the problem: in a corresponding header, a function argument was missing and the compiler didn't complain.... . The rest is ok and the world is right again. I'm not cursed ;)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem with your attempted `strcpy` call is that your destination (the `string` member of your `data`) isn't a pointer to valid memory. *(I am assuming that your invalid syntax, `strcpy((*data).string = "Hello!")` is a typo, and that your real code has something like `strcpy((*data).string, "Hello!")` – otherwise, it won't even compile, so you won't get a segmentation fault.)*

There are several approaches to fix this, depending on what you actually want to happen. First, as also mentioned in the comments, you can just copy the *pointer* to the destination, like this<sup>1</sup>:

```c
data->string = "Hello!";
```

However, this *may* not be what you want, because, if the source is not actually a literal, but a modifiable string, then, after that assignment, any changes to the source will also apply to your copy.

If you want a *copy* of the source data, you will need to allocate sufficient space for it, then call `strcpy`; like this:

```c
#include <stdlib.h> // For malloc

const char* src = "Hello!";
data->string = malloc(strlen(src) + 1); // Add 1 for the required nul-terminator
strcpy(data->string, src);
```

However, [the `strdup` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup)<sup>2</sup> does the job of the above `malloc` and `strcpy` calls in one fell swoop:

```c
data->string = strdup("Hello!");
```

In each of the above two cases, be sure to call `free(data->string)` when you're finished.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that you can use the "member access through pointer" (`->`) operator, rather than dereferencing and then using the `.` operator: `data->number = 5` is equivalent to your `(*data).number = 5`.

<sup>2</sup> Some compilers/platforms may not support the `strdup` function, but it is part of the ISO C Standard from C23

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for your long answer. IN fact, the problem was different, pls see comment to original post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand this line

```
strcpy((*data).string = "Hello!");
```

Do you mean

```
strcpy((*data).string, "Hello!");
```

I believe the issue is that your struct contain a pointer `char * string` that doesn't point to a valid allocated memory.
You can try multiple solutions

1. Have struct with predefined size

```c
typedef struct {
    int number;
    char string[100];
} mystruct;
```

2. You can allocate memory for the string during the initialization

```
data = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
data->string = malloc(sizeof(char) *100));
```

Comment: 2 is wrong. It should be `data->string` because `data` is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As other users mentioned, you need to allocate space for the string.

I would use a flexible array member and have only one allocation for the struct and string.

```
typedef struct {
    int number;
    char string[];
} mystruct;


mystruct *create(const char *str)
{
    mystruct *ms = NULL;

    if(str)
    {
        ms = malloc(sizeof(*ms) + strlen(str) + 1);
        if(ms)
        {
            strcpy(ms -> string, str);
            ms -> number = 0;
        }
    }
    return ms;
}

int main(void)
{
    mystruct *ms = create("Hello");

    if(ms)
    {
        printf("ms -> string = `%s`\n", ms -> string);
    }
    free(ms);
}
```